# How to merge columns with the nearest data-point when the data-points are of float datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Timestamp           Notif_No     Notif_Data
8517.45             1            App_ON
8518.15             2            App_DELAY
8519.26             3            App_WORK
8520.39             4            App_OFF
```

And another CSV file as:

```
Timestamp           Data
8516.11             abc
8516.21             bcd
8517.45             abc
8518.04             bcd
8518.14             zxc
8519.16             bcd
8519.26             zxc
8520.29             qwe
8520.39             abc
```

When I merge the two files according to "Timestamp":

```
Timestamp           Data        Notif_No     Notif_Data
8516.11             abc
8516.21             bcd
8517.45             abc         1            App_ON
8518.04             bcd
8518.14             zxc
8519.16             bcd
8519.26             zxc         3            App_WORK
8520.29             qwe
8520.39             abc         4            App_OFF
```

This way it misses one "Notif_No" value from the 1st CSV file. As the nearest value for "2" is "8518.14" in the previous dataframe. I want to merge according to that.
The result I want:

```
Timestamp           Data        Notif_No     Notif_Data
8516.11             abc
8516.21             bcd
8517.45             abc         1            App_ON
8518.04             bcd
8518.14             zxc         2            App_DELAY
8519.16             bcd
8519.26             zxc         3            App_WORK
8520.29             qwe
8520.39             abc         4            App_OFF
```

The explanations available on stack overflow show how to work when in datetime timestamp format but here I've the data-points in floating point seconds format. Also, the example here is quite consistent and to the point but the real life data I collect from a logger is very noisy and some has inconsistent values, as such the nearest data-point can be ranging from 0.01 seconds to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do a [`pd.merge_asof`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pd+mereasof&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=pd+mereasof&aqs=chrome..69i57.3323j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys.

```
pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='Timestamp',direction='nearest',tolerance=0.09)
```

---

```
   Timestamp Data  Notif_No Notif_Data
0    8516.11  abc       NaN        NaN
1    8516.21  bcd       NaN        NaN
2    8517.45  abc       1.0     App_ON
3    8518.04  bcd       NaN        NaN
4    8518.14  zxc       2.0  App_DELAY
5    8519.16  bcd       NaN        NaN
6    8519.26  zxc       3.0   App_WORK
7    8520.29  qwe       NaN        NaN
8    8520.39  abc       4.0    App_OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a key to join on.  The key I created below is rather crude.  I'm simply removing the last digit.  Rounding to 1 digit won't get you the match you want either.

```py
df1['key'] = df1['Timestamp'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[0:-1])
df2['key'] = df2['Timestamp'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[0:-1])

pd.merge(df2,df1[['key','Notif_No','Notif_Data']],on='key',how='left').drop(['key'],axis=1)
```

The results of this are:

```
    Data    Timestamp   Notif_No    Notif_Data
0   abc 8516.11 NaN NaN
1   bcd 8516.21 NaN NaN
2   abc 8517.45 1.0 App_ON
3   bcd 8518.04 NaN NaN
4   zxc 8518.14 2.0 App_DELAY
5   bcd 8519.16 NaN NaN
6   zxc 8519.26 3.0 App_WORK
7   qwe 8520.29 NaN NaN
8   abc 8520.39 4.0 App_OFF
```

You could replace `lambda x: x[0:-1]` with `lambda x: keyfunc(x)` and define some sort of function to manipulate the timestamp to your liking.